# Difference between in PHP shell-scripts and PHP on MAMP?

Tags: php, web

This is weird to me. I wonder why. I wrote a PHP script to validate syntax of another PHP script named **test.php**

```
 <?php
    print("Hello World");
    ?>
```

The validating script **index.php** is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
exec("php -l test.php", $error, $retcode);
echo($retcode . "<br />");
var_dump($error);
?>
```

When I run on command line **php index.php**, it generates this output:

```
0<br />array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "No syntax errors detected in test.php"
}
```

This looks good to me. However, when I run on localhost it generates this output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php 5
array(0) { }
```

Why $retcode is set to 5? Also, I'm on PHP5.3

Comment: Where are you getting $retcode being set to five?  I'm not seeing it in your example.

Comment: I already included the output screen. 5 is next to #!/usr/bin/env php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I already figured this out.

Check http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync for exit code info.

The problem is that I have to use the PHP interpreter on MAMP, which is:

```
exec("/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php -l $file",$error,$retcode);
```

The one I used before was PHP interpreter on OS X.